# Typescript Error: Type '{ props: IDrink; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IDrink'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, rtk-query

I am getting this error in my React Typescript app. Specifically, the error is happening when trying to pass props to the child component.

Here is the parent component:

```
const SearchID: FC = (): ReactElement => {
    const { id } = useParams<string>();
    const {
        data: cocktails,
        isLoading,
        error
        } = useGetCocktailByIDQuery(id ? id : "");

    if(isLoading) return <Skeleton variant="text" />
    if(error) return <div>An error has occured.</div>

  return (
    <>
        {cocktails ? <CocktailDetail props={cocktails.drinks[0]} /> : "No data"}
    </>
  );
};
```

I am able to get the console.log(props) to show up in the console, but still getting the Typescript error.
Child Component:

```
const CocktailDetail = (props: IDrink) => {
    console.log(props)
  return (
    <h1></h1>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You do not explicitly specify types in your `CocktailDetail` component, so TypeScript is finding it hard to know what props should and shouldn't exist.
2. The way you are passing props is slightly unconventional (not necessarily wrong).

What I tend to do is something like this:

```
interface IDrink {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}


interface CocktailDetailProps {
    drink: IDrink;
}

const CocktailDetail: FC<CocktailDetailProps> = ({ drink }) => {
    return (<h1></h1>);
}
```

Then use as follows:

```
const SearchID: FC = (): ReactElement => {
    const { id } = useParams<string>();
    const {
        data: cocktails,
        isLoading,
        error
        } = useGetCocktailByIDQuery(id ? id : "");

    if(isLoading) return <Skeleton variant="text" />
    if(error) return <div>An error has occured.</div>

  return (
    <>
        {cocktails ? <CocktailDetail drink={cocktails.drinks[0]} /> : "No data"}
    </>
  );
};
```